# Reading from file into 2d Array in C without constant size

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have a text file that have content like this

```
5 6
01111
11110
01000
01111
11010
11111
```

And i want to made a function read from this file and create 2d array out of the content.

Two Numbers from the first line is the size of array and the size of sub array.

The result of the function should be array like this

```
{{0,1,1,1,1}, {1,1,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0},{0,1,1,1,1},{1,1,0,1,0},{1,1,1,1,1}}
```

So how would i be able to do that?

Right now i try to made a function like this but it error

```
int** createArray(FILE *fp)
{
    int xdim;
    int ydim;
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &xdim, &ydim);

    int** arr = malloc(ydim * sizeof(*arr));;
    for (int y = 0; y < ydim; y++)
    {
        arr[y] = malloc(xdim * sizeof(**arr));
        fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %d", arr[y]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Do you have a [mcve] you can show us? Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It's pretty confusing to de-reference the array as `arr[y][x]`. Consider swapping the place of the coordinates, so they are in the same order as in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop `xdim` times over `arr[y]` then and read numbers with `fscanf`. Note that a space `" "` in `fscanf` format specifier ignores all whitespaces - tabs, spaces and newlines - so it can just read it all.

```
int** arr = malloc(ydim * sizeof(*arr));;
if (arr == NULL) {
     abort();
}

for (int y = 0; y < ydim; y++) {

    arr[y] = malloc(xdim * sizeof(*arr[y]));
    if (arr[y] == NULL) {
        abort();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < xdim; ++i) {
        char c;
        if (fscanf(fp, " %c", &c) != 1) {
            abort(); // handle error
        }
        arr[i][j] = c - '0';
    }
}
```

[Tested on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sQ5zTA).

Comment: I just try this and it keep hitting third abort() in if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &arr[y][i]) != 1) condition.

Comment: Right, because `11111` is one integer. Then read a character at a time.